# Bash Script to Remove Files Greater than 1 Week Old Using AWS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm currently working on a script to remove files from the server that are greater than one week old. I am using the AWS-CLI.

Currently the script is removing everything and then completing my backup. I'd like to keep at least 7 days and only delete files that are a week or greater in age.

```
domain=( mydomain.com )
sqldb=( mydb )
opath=$HOME/backup/
mysqlhost=mysql.mydomain.com
username=myuser
password=password
webdir=$HOME/myfolder
today=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
week=$(date --date='1 week ago' '+%m-%d-%Y')

for (( i = 0; i < ${#domain[@]}; i++))
do
        cpath=$opath${domain[$i]}
        if [ -d $cpath ]
        then
                filler="just some action to prevent syntax error"
        else
                echo Creating $cpath
                mkdir -p $cpath
        fi
        mysqldump -c -h $mysqlhost --user $username --password=$password ${sqldb[$i]} > ${cpath}/"$today"_${sqldb[$i]}.sql
        zip -r ${cpath}/"$today"_"$domain".zip $webdir

done

#delete objects older than 7 days
# aws --endpoint-url https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io s3 rm s3://my-bucket/file.txt
aws --endpoint-url https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io s3 rm --recursive s3://mybackups | grep $week

#use aws-cli to upload to DreamObjects
aws --endpoint-url https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io s3 sync $opath s3://mybackups/backups/ --exclude "$opath"mybackups.com-backup.sh

#delete backup from web server
find $HOME/backup/* -type d -exec rm -rf {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: `for (( i = 0; i < ${#domain[@]}; i++)); do echo "${domain[$i]}"; done` is much better written `for i in "${domain[@]}" ; do echo "$i" ; done`

Comment: Your removal script is removing all elements, then greping the output to only show you some of the work it did.  You'll need to produce a list of files to delete, then delete just the files you want to do.  This will be dramatically easier in language other than bash, and this has nothing to do with AWS.

Comment: Ah I see. I thought I was removing only those it grepped. I will look into doing this in PHP vs bash.